Can we measure the temperature of the condensed BEC by method of the in-situ imaging?
I study atomic physics, and I met a small problem in the imaging method of a condensed BEC. As far as I know, most group use time-of-flight imaging to determine the temperature. I would like to ask if is there any group/paper using in-situ imaging to decide the temperature of the BEC?
Further, which information can we get or infer from the method of in-situ imaging on the condensed trapped BEC?

I guess your idea is that: The hotter the atoms, the larger the cloud in a given trap size.
I consider myself to be very familiar with this field and I don't know of any simple experiment where a single in-situ image is taken to measure the temperature.
Why is that? I suppose, that temperature does not alter the in-situ cloud size enough to give a reliable measurement. In case of very low temperatures, interactions and non-linear density effect obscure a direct relation of cloud size and temperature.
Time-of-flight is very simple. Depending on the repetition rate of the apparatus, a very reliable temperature is obtained after few minutes.
This might be an unsatisfying answer. If yes, then have a look at this paper:
https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.93.043607
It's not that simple. But in principle, they use very few atoms to measure the temperature with an optical lattice. Very related to your question.

If there are spin etc., in situ florescence imaging may give you population ratio of different species, and you can in principle estimate the Boltzmann weights.  But I am only a theorist.  Ah, but I guess the paper you link to has a very similar idea?

Yes it should work, but experimental limitations in imaging (e.g. limited dynamic range of the camera and limited resolution) prevent a sensitive measurement. Also the argument with non-linear density effects remains valid.

@kai90 Thanks for your reply. I will check it out that paper.
